# Reverse engineering database : exclude some tables

Tags: php, mysql, reverse-engineering, symfony4

I'm using :

- **symfony** `4.1.6`
- **php** `7.1.17`

I want to reverse engineer a **mysql** database. Unfortunately this database does have some **tables** `without` primary keys.

I want then to skip those tables by using :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import App\Entity annotation --path=src/Entity --filter="users"
```

This filter seems not to work

I have found a solution using `schema_filter` (regexp) in `doctrine.yml` but this is no ideal (because I have to modify a configuration file on each run).

Has anyone find a filtering solution in **symfony** `4` ?

Comment: How about cloning your database and removing tables without primary key of it?

Comment: it's a solution, but not very flexible. I mean I could do this, but I have to pick table one by one, a filtering solution would be better (actually I do this but)

Comment: I don't think you'll have what you want out of the box, it's outside the scope of doctrine normal use cases.